# Is there a cleaner way to handle try/catch when checking against a boolean state?

Tags: java, exception

I want to query some state and break out of my method on a failure condition but this condition also has to guard against a checked exception.

I'm currently handling it as such:

```
try {
   if (!isSomeState()) {
      error("Failed to realize state");

      return;
   }
}
catch (SomeStateException ex) {
   error("Failed to realize state");

   return;
}
```

I could throw the checked exception to drop down into the catch block. But this feels dirty because the exception is just redirecting program flow:

```
try {
   if (!isSomeState())
      throw new SomeStateException();
}
catch (SomeStateException ex) {
   error("Failed to realize state");

   return;
}
```

It doesn't make sense to have the method throw this exception because I'm meant to handle it in this method as described.

**Update:**

To clarify, the state being queried utilizes socket i/o and therefore is throwing a extension of `IOException`; so the exception itself is not superfluous in this case.

The resulting boolean expresses whether some state is set to `true` or `false`. It does NOT make sense to return `false` on this exception as there will be no point in continuing to query for additional state which could otherwise be valid on `false`.

Comment: change `isSomeState` method so that it throws `SomeStateException` instead of returning `false`

Comment: I've added some additional clarification as to what the boolean state is meant to express. `false` is a valid result whereas the exception expresses some `IOException`.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify `isSomeState` so that it returns `false` instead if throwing an exception. Then all you need to do is simply:

```
if (!isSomeState()) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: The state is not always `false` on an `IOException`; it may actually be `true` but unreachable, hence the exception.

Comment: @Zhro Don't you control it? I mean you can return whatever you want based on your logic, no?

Comment: It depends on whether I want to act on the state or check to see if it is accessible. These two queries are mutually exclusive. It just so happens that in my example the action to report an error and return are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below logic, it is more readable:

```
boolean flag = false;
try
{
    flag = isSomeState();
}
catch(SomeStateException e)
{
    // log here too.
    flag = false;
}
finally
{
    if(!flag)
    {
        error("Failed to realize state");
        return;
    }
}
```